# tikz - align node vertically in foreach loop

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

I want to align nodes in foreach loop vertically!

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,convert={outfile=\jobname.png}]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{fmtcount}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=0]
\tikzset{box/.style={draw}}
\foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \p using \i-1] in {0,...,5} {
    \pgfmathsetmacro\addr{int(0xbc - \i)}
    \def\hexaddr{0xE056\Hexadecimalnum{\addr}}
    \ifnum\i=0
        \node[box,label={left:\hexaddr}] (N\i) {\i};
    \else
        \node[box,label={left:\hexaddr},below=0cm of N\p] (N\i) {\i};
    \fi
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But now the output is:
[image]

I guess I should change the `N\p` to `N\p.south west` but it can not compile.

Comment: `\i as \p using  int(\i-1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression `evaluate=\i as \p using \i-1` when `\i > 0` results in `0.0, 1.0, 2.0, ..., 4.0` and you mean `0, 1, 2, ..., 4`, so you can choose `count=\p from -1` or as noted out by @percusse in a comment `\i as \p using int(\i-1)`.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,convert={outfile=\jobname.png}]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{fmtcount}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=0]
\tikzset{box/.style={draw}}
\foreach \i [count=\p from -1] in {0,...,5} {
    \pgfmathsetmacro\addr{int(0xbc - \i)}
    \def\hexaddr{0xE056\Hexadecimalnum{\addr}}
    \ifnum\i=0
        \node[box,label={left:\hexaddr}] (N\i) {\i};
    \else
        \node[box,label={left:\hexaddr},below=0cm of N\p] (N\i) {\i};
    \fi
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: hmmm, sounds weird, that means in my code, N1.0 actually does exist, compile should report error then we can know it's not a valid node at all.

Answer (score 2):

You can use chain as below:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,convert={outfile=\jobname.png}]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{fmtcount}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,shapes}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain=values going below,node distance=0,outer sep=0]
\tikzset{box/.style={draw}}
\foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \p using \i-1] in {0,...,5} {
    \pgfmathsetmacro\addr{int(0xbc - \i)}
    \def\hexaddr{0xE056\Hexadecimalnum{\addr}}
    \node[box,on chain,label={left:\hexaddr}] (N\i) {\i};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]